# I am getting this error in docker toolbox. How to resolve it?

Tags: docker

[I am getting this error in docker toolbox. please tell me how to resolve this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJKrR.jpg)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi Karan, please update your question. You are asking for help so please be considerate to not load unnecessary work to volunteers. Neither your question is searchable nor does it push peoples motiviation to answer your question, when the information is in a linked image instead of written down.

Comment: related to the last comment : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479251